# Create node on condition

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to make a relationship between nodes in Neo4j if a certain condition is met like. Currently I have node(a) and node(b):

What I want

```
if node(b) is in label1 then make relation: node(a)-[:r]-node(b:label1)
else merge node(b) in label2 then make relation node(a)-[:r]-node(b:label2)
```

What I have

```
match (a:label1 {id:"t1"}) 
merge (b:label1 {id:"t6"})
on create 
  set b:label2 remove b:label1 
merge (a)-[:Friends_with]-(b)
```

Comment: Formatted code in edit window.  See { } icon on top of the edit window.

Comment: Can you share your query so far, and how it's failing?

Comment: match (nodea:label1 {id:"t1"}) 
merge (nodeb:label1 {id:"t6"}) 
on create set nodeb:label2 remove nodeb:label1 
merge (nodea)-[:Friends_with]-(nodeb)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Cypher doesn't really have an if-then-else syntax (ON MATCH and ON CREATE is the closest you will get). I would recommend running running multiple cyphers and executing follow-ups based on the return result.

So like

```
MATCH (a:label1 {id:"t1"}) 
MATCH (b:label1 {id:"t6"})
MERGE (a)-[:Friends_with]-(b)
return COUNT(b) as b1Exists
```

And if that returns 0, then execute

```
MATCH (a:label1 {id:"t1"}) 
MERGE (b:label2 {id:"t6"})
MERGE (a)-[:Friends_with]-(b)
```

Depending on your data, you might get away with this

```
MATCH (a:label1 {id:"t1"}) 
MERGE (b {id:"t6"})
ON CREATE SET b:label2
MERGE (a)-[:Friends_with]-(b)
```

But just know that doing this in 1 Cypher will probably result in bugs (In this case, if there are more valid labels than 1 and 2. You will want a UUID for this method)